# How to delete a list item in Fragment A, from Fragment B?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Simple enough but I don't know the correct approach to this problem.

I have Fragment A which is a list of items. And Fragment B is a detail view of a single selected item. In Fragment B I have a delete action button that obviously should delete the current item. But how would I remove that list item from a different Fragment? Should I use a listener for when the delete button is pressed and then from the activity delete the item?

What's the best approach for this problem?

Comment: Is the data bound to the `ListView` local to the Fragment A? I guess no if you'd like to delete one entry in Fragment B. So, back to the Fragment A, you can simply refresh the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the way to do this is through the activity, as fragments better not be aware of each other.

The way to do that is to define an interface like so:

```
interface FragmentBListener {
    void onDelete();
}
```

And register listeners with FragmentB:

```
class FragmentB extends Fragment ... {
    private FragmentBListener _listener;

    public void setListener(FragmentBListener listener) { _listener = listener ;}

    // And in your Delete button handler:
    private void onDeleteButton() {
        _listener.onDelete();
    }
}
```

Now implement the interface in your activity:

```
class MyActivity implements FragmentBListener {

    // Instantiate the fragments:
    private void initFragments() {
        ...
        _fragmentB.setListener(this);
    }

    public void onDelete() {
        _fragmentA.delete(...);
    }
}
```

It's a bit verbose, but it leaves the fragments independent of each other, which may be important.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good but just to add another alternative, starting API 17 you could make Fragment B a child of Fragment A by using `getChildFragmentManager()`. This would allow you to use `getParentFragment()` in Fragment B. If one fragment logically should be the child of another, this would be the best choice.

But this would make the app incompatible with Android versions < 4.2, so it's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I am researching [Android EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus%22EventBus%22) open source lib. Please check that. It is a very useful tool to solve the communication among every component, including activity, fragment, service, broadcast and so on.

I believe this kind of tools can play an important role in Android, which includes different components/modules.